# how to change particular tr bgcolor in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having multiple tr with bgcolors like

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr bgcolor="#000000">
<tr bgcolor="#D30A0A">
```

I want to specify the particular tr and change its bgcolor in javascript OR CSS without using id value.
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but what is so *specific* about it?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. How do you know which `tr` you want to modify? Do you want to do it be the current color or the position in the table or the content or...?

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByTagName` is what you are looking for. It is returning an array of DOM element. Like every good array object, you can select by index the targeted `tr` :

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[indexOfYourTR].setAttribute('bgcolor', '#FFFF00')
```

If you want to be more specific, you can chain the `getElement` method. For example :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1].getElementsByTagName('tr')[3].setAttribute('bgcolor', '#FFFF00');
```

This will change the 4th row of the 2nd table in the document.

Comment: How to identify the specific tr index?

Comment: @user3152748 From the DOM order!

Comment: This will change the 4th row of the 2nd table in the document. or This will change the 3rd row of the 1st table in the document.????

Comment: @user3152748 the 4th row of the 2nd table since it is based on a 0 index (`0 = 1st, 1 = 2nd, 2 = 3rd ...`)!

Answer (score 0):

With CSS, you can use:

```
.parent_element:nth-child(1){ /*Matches the second <tr> in .parent_element*/
}
```

or:

```
tr:nth-of-type(1){ /*Matches every <tr> which is the 
                     second element of type tr within
                     its parent*/
}
```

[More about CSS3 :nth-child().](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

[More about CSS3 :nth-of-type().](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

Comment: can u please explain this?

Comment: I commented the code and added links to documentation.